# Don't clear COOKIES on linux (apache 5) but on windows (same version of apache) clears

Tags: php, apache, cookies

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
$cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
    $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
    $name = trim($parts[0]);
    setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
    setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

Don't clear COOKIES on linux (Apache 5) but on windows (same version of Apache) clears

This is the code of PHP and what may be problem?

Comment: don't use relative times for cookie clearing. you're depending on the client clocks being "close" to accurate. Set a LONG past date, e.g. Jan 1/1970. Anyone who's on a PC with a clock that inaccurate doesn't deserve to be surfing a functional web.

Answer (score 0):

`time()-1000` is not very far in the past.

I suspect the difference is just in the system time of the two computers.

If you want to delete a cookie, set the expiry to a time in the 1970s.